# How can I reset $PATH to its default value in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I accidentally unset all the directories of `$PATH` while trying to add a new one in `~/.bashrc`. I opened a new terminal window as I was editing and now `$PATH` is empty. I'm worried if I boot from another drive to find the `$PATH` I won't be able to boot into this drive again.

Basically, what is the default result of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Comment out or fix that export line and you should e good to go.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is the wrong place to set environment variables though. You should do that in `~/.profile` instead.

Comment: Yes I figured it out. PATH is still fine in the other terminal window that was open before the new one, so just fixing the export line by adding `:$PATH` at the end restored the PATH. And yes in `~/.profile` there is code to "set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists" i.e. `$HOME/bin`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding :$PATH to the end of the export line fixed the problem e.g. `export PATH=<directory to be added>:$PATH`

I add this line to the `~/.bash_rc` file instead of the `~/.profile` file so I can see the effect immediately in a new terminal and for other reasons based on the information here: https://superuser.com/questions/176404/linux-bash-not-loading-profile-in-new-session

For me, the default output of `echo $PATH` before adding the new directory is:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Answer (score 51):

The answer to your question is:

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH)
```

and works on any POSIX compliant system.  The selected answer is the correct way to augment the path without obliterating prior existing content.  If you use bash, you might consider:

```
PATH+=:$mynewdir
```

Comment: I had trouble using a lot of commands (`sed: No such file or directory` type of trouble) after accidentally setting my PATH to nothing during a very long running process (i.e., I couldn't restart). I couldn't use `getconf`. 
To reset my path, I used `$(export $(cat /etc/environment)":/usr/bin/additional:/usr/bin/paths")`. For the curious: `/etc/environment` is where the PATH variable is initially set in many Linux flavours.

Comment: That working would surprise me.  Perhaps "export" without the surrounding "$(...)" stuff might, but it will be whatever happens to be there.  Use "source /etc/..".  Anyway, try "/usr/bin/getconf" if you cannot even find "getconf".

Comment: Prefer your final idea using the full path a lot more than mine in hindsight! Thanks for the reply

Comment: If the PATH variable is empty, then `PATH=$(getconf PATH)` will not be useful but only result in `bash: getconf: No such file or directory`

Comment: If PATH is empty, then note the comment above: try "/usr/bin/getconf". If that does not work, then you need to learn where your system stashes its POSIX commands and use that directory.

Comment: `/usr/bin/getconf` should be added to the answer itself. This works.

Comment: Most cleverly, not all systems put POSIX commands in /usr/bin. It is system dependent. SO: 1- get to know your systems, and 2- /usr/bin/getconf works 99% :)

Answer (score 29):

You can find it on /etc/environment:

```
$ /usr/bin/cat /etc/environment

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

So, just source it:

```
$ source /etc/environment 
$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 4):

The default path is

```
/home/_username_/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: That differs from my default PATH. See below.