# How to reset the PATH value for bash shell

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, paths

I tried installing hadoop and I no longer need stuff from it.
When launching shell , it gives the following and many commands are unrecognized now , how do I reset it to default ?

```
bash: export:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:
/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/hadoop/bin': not a valid
identifier astitva@astitva-Vostro-3446:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reset $PATH to its default value in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113419/how-can-i-reset-path-to-its-default-value-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out :)
just did the following and it worked :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/s
bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$PATH
```

Comment: Yes, you assign a variable with `varname=...` not `$varname=...`

Comment: And note that you are not *resetting* the path, and you are not removing anything from it: you are adding several directories to the beginning of it. To actually reset it: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$(getconf PATH):/usr/games:/usr/local/games`