# Overwrote $PATH

Tags: system-installation, java, environment-variables, paths

I am new to linux and I was trying to set up path of JAVA_HOME but I accidentally wrote
`export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
which I think overwrote $PATH.

I am quite sure I have messed up big time. Because when I enter $PATH, it says `zsh: no such file or directory: /home/gshacklebolt/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Is there any way to revert what I did?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reset $PATH to its default value in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/113419/) and [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Comment: @karel yep thanks for the help.

Comment: If this link answered your question you can confirm it by clicking the link in the blue banner above your question's body text block.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the PATH you need to type

```
echo $PATH
```

I think the original path should be restored after a reboot.
And then to add a new dir to the path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/add_tour_path_here
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I have rebooted the system and on entering $PATH this is what i get ```zsh: no such file or directory: /home/gshacklebolt/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games```

Comment: Typing `$PATH` means that you want to run the contents of your PATH variable as a command - which would definitely not work, hence the error message. But this message quotes the command you tried to run, which is `/home/gshacklebolt/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` - so that is your PATH. As written in the answer, if you want to display your PATH, type `echo $PATH`, not just `$PATH`.